# Time per state per user in Rally

Tags: rally, rallyapi

I want to create a custom report where I want to know the time spent by each owner(user) in a specific user story based on schedule state in Rally.
We have Time per state per story but it does not show based on owner.

I am trying to do it by fetching the revision history of each user story and then generating the required report.Is there a way to get the report in Rally itself

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.